# Why are the layer ids of my map service changing when I refresh the map service endpoint in the browser?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, map-service, arcgis-web-adaptor

I go to the endpoint for my cached map service and view the layers and their IDs that are in the service:

```
T201510cm (93)
  Boundary (94)
  Footprint (95)
  Image (96)
T201520cm (0)
  Boundary (97)
  Footprint (98)
  Image (99)
```

When I refresh the service, the IDs of the layers change:

```
T201510cm (93)
  Boundary (94)
  Footprint (95)
  Image (96)
T201520cm (1852394799)
  Boundary (1852394800)
  Footprint (1852394801)
  Image (1852394802)
```

and:

```
T201510cm (97)
  Boundary (94)
  Footprint (95)
  Image (96)
T201520cm (93)
  Boundary (98)
  Footprint (99)
  Image (100)
```

It seems that there are three unique sets of IDs that are being applied.

The service is assigned to a cluster with 2 machines. I thought maybe the machines in the cluster got out of sync or something and the web adapter is bouncing back and forth to the 2 different actual machines with different IDs on each of those, but the fact that there are *two* machines and *three* unique combinations of IDs might point against that.

Why are my IDs getting juggled around?

I can not provide the endpoint, but here are (redacted) screenshots of the endpoint from the browser:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the REST URL if it is publically accessible?

Comment: I can't add the endpoint URL, but have added screenshots above